# django urls не могу понять почему в url попадают эти символы

Tags: python, django

Я новичок, пытаюсь написать простой Django проект. все работает, все выводится, 
но при обращении страны сайта в URL появляются доп символы, не могу понять что это такое и как это убрать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .models import Engless
# Create your views here.

class IndexPageView(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'index.html'

class EnlangPageView(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'eng.html'

class RulangPageView(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'rus.html'
```

код urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'lang'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexPageView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('/eng/', views.EnlangPageView.as_view(), name='eng'),
    path('/rus/', views.RulangPageView.as_view(), name='rus'),
    path('/eng/getlesson/', views.GetLessonTemplate),
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%2F` — это закодированный символ `/`.

Он появился, потому что Вы начали с него Ваш путь в `urls.py`:

```py
'127.0.0.1:8000/' + '/eng/getlesson/' = '127.0.0.1:8000//eng/getlesson/'
#              ^     ^                                 ^^
```

Исправьте Ваш код следующим образом:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexPageView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('eng/', views.EnlangPageView.as_view(), name='eng'),
    path('rus/', views.RulangPageView.as_view(), name='rus'),
    path('eng/getlesson/', views.GetLessonTemplate),
]
```